# li action not working when add element from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this div

```
<div class="foodsSection">
    <label>
        Foods:
    </label>
    <ul>
        <li>
            roma
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this jquery:

```
$(".foodsSection li").click(function(){
        $(".addressesSection").css("display","block");
    });
```

when I press on `roma` the jquery is working good, but when i press on any `li` that comes from database using jquery, the jquery is not working, this is the jquery which take the data form database and but it in `li` elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".RestauranstSection li").click(function (){
        var divYourOrder = $(".YourOrder");
        var li = $(".OMRestaurants li");
        $(".foodsSection").css("display", "block");
        var restaurantID = 8;
        var foodDive = $(".foodsSection ul");
        foodDive.html("");
        var lis = '';
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/TheEatTel/Food/getFoodForRestaurant/"+restaurantID+"/TRUE",function(data){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i=i+3){
                lis +="<li id='"+data[i+2]+"'>"+"<label>"+data[i]+"</label> <label>"+data[i+1]+"</label></li>";
            }
            lis+="";
            foodDive.html(lis);    
        });
    });
    $(".foodsSection li").click(function(){
        $(".addressesSection").css("display","block");
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate since the question didn't mention `on`.

Comment: @dystroy how it is duplicated please?, i didn't know that `on` is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use *.on()* instead of *.click()* because the click method does not work on DOM which has been generated.

```
$(".foodsSection li").on("click", 'li' ,function(){
    $(".addressesSection").css("display","block");
});
```

Comment: +1 to you ,thank you, i will accept your answer

Comment: Is this a new way of chaining methods?

Comment: Oops, no. I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: FYI, it doesn't delegate the event. Please see other answers. Edit: now, you should remove the first `li`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
$(".foodsSection ul").on('click', 'li', function(){
```

The jQuery set on which you're calling the binding function is computed when you do the binding. When the event is received, it checks the selector you passed as argument. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: yes you right, it works, but what is your way deffer from my way? and why in my way the code just works form static `li` elementns?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli The `.click()` method you are using doesn't handle Delegated (future created) bubble events.  In this method, `li`'s that are clicked with the parent of `.foodsSection` will trigger this event.

Answer (score 1):

Use Delegated events, like

```
$(".foodsSection").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(".addressesSection").css("display","block");
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ (and read especially the part about Direct and delegated events, which explains why your code does not work and this code *does*)

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be

```
$('.foodsSection').on('click', 'li', function() {
});
```

The problem in your code is, that you attach listeners on each existing 'li' elements at that moment. Otherwise when you use `.on('click', 'li', function(){})` you attach your listener to parent element, so it could handle all clicks on it's child